# Pasting choice from a applescript list into any application

Tags: applescript

I am new to applescript, and am only here because I need a solution.
I want to be able to choose from a list and have the information go into a box, no matter which app.
I have a script that gives me a list and I can select.
But dont know how to get it to paste into the area or box.

```
set emailaddress to {"email address 1", "email address 2", "email address 3", "email address 4"}

set emailaddress to choose from list emailaddress with prompt "Select your Email:" default items "email address 1"
emailaddress
--> Result: email address 1
```

Thanks

Larry

Answer (score 0):

First of all the result is `{email address 1}` because `choose from list` returns a list.

To be able to paste the address put it on the clipboard

```
set addresses to {"email address 1", "email address 2", "email address 3", "email address 4"}

set emailaddress to choose from list addresses with prompt "Select your Email:" default items "email address 1"
if emailaddress is false then return -- catch the case that the user presses the Cancel button
set the clipboard to item 1 of emailaddress -- flatten the list
```

Then you can press <kbd>⌘V</kbd>

Comment: Thanks Vadian Brilliant.
Is there any way to get it to go straight in without going through clipboard?

Comment: No, because the target can be anything and for inserting the text directly you have to specify the target.